# Update Linq database field depending on searched value - Password change

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, linq

I have a VB.net LINQ program that allows a user to enter an email address.  The email address is checked against a database table called 'User_signon' which has the fields 'Email (PK)' and 'Password'   When "btnPassword" is clicked the email address is checked against the database and a randomly generated password is emailed to the email address.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the new random password to update in the database to connect with the email address.  I have the following code but i am missing a way of updating the password.

'establish connection with database
            Dim db As New DatabaseDataClassesDataContext()

```
        'initialise global variabel to take email string entered in text box
        GlobalVariables.SearchUserEmail = txtEmailAddress.Text

        'initialise global variable to hold email address retrieved from database
        GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress = (From u In db.User_Signons
                                               Where u.Email = SearchUserEmail
                                               Select u.Email).First

       'calls generatepassword method
        Dim stNewPassword As String = GeneratePassword()
```

Any help out there please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just fetching the username, fetch the entire user object and then set the password and save the result. See if the following helps:

```
    'initialise global variabel to take email string entered in text box
    GlobalVariables.SearchUserEmail = txtEmailAddress.Text

    'initialise global variable to hold email address retrieved from database
    Dim user = db.User_Signons.First(Function(u) u.Email = SearchUserEmail)
    GlobalVariables.CurrentEmailAddress = user.UserEmail

   'calls generatepassword method
    Dim stNewPassword As String = GeneratePassword()
    user.Password = stNewPassword
    db.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: thank you very much for you reply and solution.  Implemented and working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
Dim user= (From u In db.User_Signons Where     u.Email = SearchUserEmail Select u.Email).First;

user.password =stNewPassword
db.SaveChanges();
```

And thats it.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  i tried this out and it works.  i went with the code below in the end but thank you